# A-frame Random page reloads/refresh

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, aframe

I've been working on a VR game within A-Frame. When I started testing on devices (iPhone 7/iPhone 7 Plus running Safari, and Samsung Galaxy S6 running Chrome), I began to notice the page would randomly refresh, which is an issue for us, as it restarts the game.

This is happening with the demos on their website, as well as our self-hosted game.

Has anyone experienced this issue, and/or know what the issue or the solution is?

Comment: Does this happen in every aframe.io demo ? Is it crashing or just refreshing the aframe canvas ? Does it happen on Your galaxy S6 when running firefox ?

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing memory issues multiple times, when using iOS systems, rarely on androids.
My issues were related to memory leaks, or high memory usage causing my site to crash.
It was happening mostly, when i tried loading a highRes photo on click, and apparently stuff in `<a-assets>` is cached partially, so Your site does not load for a day, but it uses up way to much resources when loading stuff from there dynamically.
 My solution, as i had little time to further investigate this issue, was loading all assets on the scene, either somewhere You can't see them, or making them invisible by setting visible to false. When switching visible-not visible, I didn't have so much memory issues, so phones could handle it, but it took longer to load.
a-frame had issues with performance on mobile [before](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/1171), and I found [this guy](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/1626) had the same issues as me. It's working way better, then when those posts are from ( 2016 ), but i still have problems, solved by such workarounds. 
I hope this could solve Your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response Piotr. It's strange that I am not hearing more about this when it's happening with A-Frame examples on a fresh iPhone 7. Unfortunately, there is not a lot I can do about this. The only relevant solutions require me to remove many assets but that seems to be something I cannot do for this project.